# how to remove request parameter in layered navigation

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation

In layered navigation it is required to make custom parameter in remove link for triggering proper removal in this filter, to have possibility to save filter state in session and be able to remove this filter as well.

I using following approach:

```
public function apply(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request, $filterBlock)
{
    if ($request->getParam('delete_filter') == 1) {
        $request->setParam('delete_filter', 0);
        Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->unsFilterSettings();
        return $this;
    }
   // create filter from customer session paramteres
```

I am using Ajax filter and can't get rid of this `delete_filter` param, is it possible to patch request on the fly and remove this parameter ? I tried `clearParams()` - no luck

Comment: in the layered navigation if the parameter is not in url it's automatically removed.

Comment: yes, thats why i need somehow to separate removal from empty parameter of this filter (if its empty to make filter from session) and trying to use custom parameters like this one. but cant get rid of it

Comment: did you adding this in session? what is your current url?

Comment: `/category_url/filter/LANGUAGE/25,35.html?delete_languages=1&isLayerAjax=1` the LANGUAGE is the subject filter param

Comment: you want to remove the language param 25?

Comment: basically, yes, `25,35` to remove

Comment: you have to remove from url llok like  `/category_url/filter/LANGUAGE/.html?delete_languages=1&isLayerAjax=1` it will auto delete that param